# Javascript Fullscreen Background Slideshow help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, background, slideshow

I'm new to Javascript, and have a code that's almost perfect but needs a bit of tweaking for my needs.

Right now this code generates a fullscreen background slideshow in the body of my page, whereas I want it to do exactly the same job but applied to specific divs by ID. I also would like it to have the option to be randomised if possible.

I would be enormously grateful for any help. Thanks.

```
<style>
body {
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: center;
}
</style>

<script language="JavaScript1.2">

    //Specify background images to slide
    var bgslides=new Array()
    bgslides[0]="images/tickets1.jpg"
    bgslides[1]="images/tickets2.jpg"
    bgslides[2]="images/tickets3.jpg"

    //Specify interval between slide (in miliseconds)
    var speed=3000

    //preload images
    var processed=new Array()
    for (i=0;i<bgslides.length;i++){
    processed[i]=new Image()
    processed[i].src=bgslides[i]
    }

    var inc=-1

    function slideback(){
    if (inc<bgslides.length-1)
    inc++
    else
    inc=0
    document.body.background=processed[inc].src
    }

    if (document.all||document.getElementById)
    window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideback()",speed)')

</script>
```

Comment: you can try with some plugin??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function slideback(){
       var imageToShow;
       imageToShow=$(bgslides).eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * bgslides.length)].src;
       document.body.background=imageToShow;
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
function slideback(){
       var imageToShow;
       var imageToPick=pickRandrom(bgslides.length);
       imageToShow=$(bgslides).eq(imageToPick].src;
       document.body.background=imageToShow;
}

function pickRandom(range)
{
    if (Math.random)
           return Math.round(Math.random() * (range-1));
    else {
           var now = new Date();
           return (now.getTime() / 1000) % range;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but is that supposed to be *instead of* the existing function slideback part? I've tried doing that but seems to break the slideshow.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be so.. By _break the slideshow_ what do you mean?

Comment: It no longer shows up at all. Am I supposed to amend the code you gave me somehow so it fits in?

Comment: Hi, no luck with that either I'm afraid! Just stops the slideshow from turning on at all :(

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle??